# what does this statement do? `nums[i] *= nums[i - 1] or 1`

Tags: python, list

While going through solutions of [maximum product subarray](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-subarray/) at leetcode, I found an intriguing solution

```
def maxProduct(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    B = nums[::-1]
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        nums[i] *= nums[i - 1] or 1
        B[i] *= B[i - 1] or 1
        # print(nums)
        # print(B)
    return max(nums + B)
```

I can't figure out how this code works, specifically what does `or 1` mean in the expression

Comment: A series of expressions connected by `or`s evaluates to the leftmost expression that has a "truthy" value - which for numeric types, means "nonzero".  So this is equal to `nums[I - 1]` if that isn't zero, otherwise 1.

Comment: It's parsed as `B[i] *= (B[i-1] or 1)`. Basically, don't zero out the product if `B[i-1]` is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this `nums[i] *= nums[i - 1] or 1` You have to understand two things:

1. Operator Precedence (refer this [Python Operator Precedence](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/python-operator-precedence/))
2. Shorthand operator

Let's break it down:
We have this syntax for shorthand operator:

```
a = a + 10 means a += 10
```

So, `var = var * value` menas `var *= value(or statement)`

Here, `or` keyword execute first. So if value B[i - 1] in current execution is zero(Boolean value False) then it will execute `0 or 1` and return 1.

This way, it can prevent 0 from multiplying all over the list item.

So,

```
nums[i] *= nums[i - 1] or 1
```

is equivalent to,

```
nums[i] = nums[i] * (nums[i - 1] or 1)
```